# How to find previous active control: Delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to get the previous active control in Delphi, i have tried to used OnActiveControlChange event, but even through that i can get the current active control not the previous one.

Thanks for the help in advance.
--Vijay

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this Code

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ---
  --- 
  private
    { Private declarations }
    wcActive, wcPrevious : TWinControl;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure ActiveControlChanged(Sender: TObject) ;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ActiveControlChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  wcPrevious := wcActive;
  wcActive := Form1.ActiveControl;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.OnActiveControlChange := ActiveControlChanged;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.OnActiveControlChange := nil;
end;
```

Use `wcControl.Name` to get the name of previous control

For more information go through [this link](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2003/a/bltip0803_4.htm)

Comment: Thanks bharat I missed this simple logic

Answer (score 5):

You could build yourself a 'history' of active controls using this event, and to find the previous you would consult your history list.

Comment: Thanks Miller maintaining history helps me to solve another issue